# How to get rid of forward slash in Python raw_input()

Tags: python, forward, slash, raw-input

Beginner programmer here. So bear with me. I have a simple python program.

```
print "How tall are you?",
height = raw_input()

print "So you're %r tall" %(height)
```

If I enter the height as 6'6'' python would output

So you're '6\6"'

How do I get rid of the forward slash "\" from the output?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem is not due to raw_input, but how you are printing. Just use `%s` instead of `%r`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`%r` converts to the repr of height, you should use `%s` instead

If you are using Python >=2.6, you can write it this way instead

```
print "So you're {height} tall.".format(height=height)
```

Comment: What's the advantage of use %r vs. %s? Is there any case I should use %r instead of %s?

Comment: What could be the reasons I can't reproduce his error? Do you happen to know?

Comment: @Jordan, It doesn't make sense to talk about an advantage. They do different things. You should use whichever is appropriate for your task. Why don't you experiment and see how their output differs for other types ints/tuples/lists/dicts.

Comment: @Trufa, maybe you didn't have the `"` on the end. Try with the input `6'6"`